# Calculate voltage

Tags: microcontroller, arm, cortex-m0

[image]I am using Bluetooth Low Energy Boards Based on Nordic nRF51822, which has  ARM Cortex-M0 microcontroller. I have 7 switches. There is always only one of them ON.  I need to know which switch is ON base on different voltages on an analogue pin . How to calculate the 7 different voltage numbers that I will get through three resistors and switches? Thanks for any help [![enter image description here][2]][2]

In my schematic I am using ATMEGA328P but I will use  ARM Cortex-M0 microcontroller

Comment: With that schematic as drawn you'll always have 0V no matter what. But assuming you rewire them correctly, what part of the standard voltage divider equation are you having trouble with?

Comment: All three tags are irrelevant because this question boils down to simple resistor dividers and ohms law. Ditto what @brhans says. Also, is the PIO pin capable of reading an analogue value?

Comment: Oh sorry my bad. I will connect it to a analogue input.

Comment: @brhans I have no idea how to fix it. I want to know which switch is ON by checking the voltage on an analogue pin. That's why I added those resistors. Can you please kindly let me know how to design the circuit board (rewiring it) and also how to read the different voltages?

Comment: Your switches are drawn incorrectly.  They are shown as SPDT, and you have nets coming off the NO (normally open) pins at the bottom and NC (normally closed) at top, but nothing off of the common to the left.  So nothing every gets connected.  You need to wire to the NO pin and common.

Comment: @tcrosley Can you please let me know how to rewire them? I mean in a simple schematic way

Comment: I'm not in a position to upload a drawing where I am (mobile), but all you have to do, for example, is move the wire connected to the pin next to the label S2, down to the left to the pin where the red wire is.  Repeat for the other two switches.  Then when the switch is closed, that will be connected to the bottom pin.

Comment: @tcrosley oh thanks yes yes this drawing is not the original one. I just wanted to show the whole concept. So after rewiring it, do you know what are the 3 voltages I am gonna get in my input for different switches?

Comment: Umm.. you've also got both ends connected to ground (assuming Vss = ground).

Comment: Hey, you've completely changed the schematic and deleted the original. That makes @MikeP 's answer nonsense. Not good.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany sorry but I tried to fixed it the way you friends told me. Is it gonna be bad for @MikeP???? It is my first time in this website. forgive me guys if I dont know the rules

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See table below, it covers all combinations of switches (individual, none, and combinations).  Total conductance is easily calculated with sumprod, inverted to make resistance, then divided with 850.

[image]

Comment: Only one of them is always ON. They are Normally open. I dont see in your calculation when for example only 220 is ON. And can you please let me know how you calculate them? People are saying my wiring is not working

Comment: Oh yes, for SW2 only, the radio is 0.79.  If you look at the bottom row you will see the formula used for each column.

Answer (score 1):

The switched resistor (call it Rs) and R9 form a voltage divider.

The voltage between Rs and R9 will be $$V_{in}\frac{R_9}{R_s + R_9}$$

according to the standard formula for a voltage divider.

Note that if no switch is pressed then Rs is infinity, so the voltage at the analogue pin is zero. If multiple switches are pressed then Rs is the parallel combination of their corresponding resistor values.

Comment: I previously confused R9 and Rs; I've fixed the formula and "the voltage at the analog pin is zero" (this previously said it was equal to Vin).